# carousel with text below

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a carousel for a main page, I was first using bootstrap but I need the text and a button to show below the carrousel and I need that text to change according to the slide. This is what I need to do.
[The carousel design in Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJsSy.png)

I researched for carousel examples but nothing similar can be done, at least with boostrap, so what I'm thinking is to make a second carousel with only text and the button just below the frist one and make it respond to the same arrow at the same time. Is it possible? heehe or is there another way I haven't seen yet? I'm a noobie with the frontend, so I apologize if I'm asking something really easy to solve. Also I'm not asking for code, I need options to explore, I will really appreciate your help, guys. :)

Comment: "Nothing similar can be done, at least with Boostrap"?  See the Bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/.  You may need make it more clear what limitation your are finding.

Comment: Here are a couple options: 1. Style the Bootstrap carousel images and the supplementary content the way you want it to look -- there are very few limitations. 2. Bind the Bootstrap events to update content according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the CSS for *.carousel-caption*: Change *position: absolute;* to *position: static;*. See here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2312